# fixed psudo element after tr tag

Tags: html, css

In the below fiddle the extra `td` elements in the non fixed tr tags are visible during scroll. 
The extra td is something like a delete button which should be hidden below fixed tr tags during scroll. Is it possible to hide just by using pure css?
something like this

```
.fixedTr td:last:after{
  ...something
}
```

***[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8w4qac30/10/)***

Comment: What you want to achieve please elaborate clearly??

Comment: Scroll completely to the right and then scroll vertically...i dont want the additional td elements in the body to align with fixed tr tags...they should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Substitute:

```
$('.firstTr > td').css('top', _top);
```

with

```
$('.firstTr > td').css('top', _top-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding extra `td`, just remove extra `<td>Something</td>` from every `tr` except `firstTr`

Or this `css` can help.

```
tr > td:last-child{
 display:none;

}
tr.firstTr > td:last-child{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

**Edit**

Use this function on scroll

```
$('table').scroll(function () {
  var _left = $(this).scrollLeft();
  var _top = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('.firstTd').css('left', _left);
  $('.firstTr > th').css('top', _top);

  if($(this).scrollTop() > 20){
    $('tr > td:last-child').hide();
  }
  else $('tr > td:last-child').show();
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w4qac30/13/)

Comment: the extra td is something like delete button ...i need that but when i scroll it should be hidden below the fixed tr tags

Comment: Instead of that, i can add colspan=2 to the last td of fixed tr using Jquery. But i want to achieve it using css